# Can't match string which stored in SQLite

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

In part of my application I get date from mobile and store it in SQLite Database as string.

when I try to select rows from database which have same date, can't find any match result.

Also as in below code, I tried to get specific cell of table which I'M sure it's match the current date. but no match.

is there any idea?

Get Date from mobile and insert it as string.

```
String currentDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
MyDB.insertRow(currentDateString);
```

Check if date from database equal mobile date.

```
if (MyDB.getRow(21).getString(1).toString()==currentDateString)
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't match `Strings` in Java using `==` operator. You use `.equals()` method as String is not a primitive type.

So try this -

```
if (MyDB.getRow(21).getString(1).toString().equals(currentDateString))
```

Comment: Thank you, it's ok for the if statement.

Comment: It's ok for the if statement.
so how I can update specific row (where clause) in database

    public boolean updateRow( String Site_par,String AttDate_Par) {
  String where =AttDate + " = " + AttDate_Par;

  ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
  newValues.put(Site,Site_par);
  newValues.put(AttDate, AttDate_Par);

  // Insert it into the database.
  return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Strings aren't matched by == operator because it is an object.

**try**

```
 MyDB.getRow(21).getString(1).toString().equals(currentDateString)
```

and if you need it **not case sensitive**

```
 MyDB.getRow(21).getString(1).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(currentDateString)
```

**Also** 
make sure that the inserted date **format** is the same that you match with